# How to get UserId in OAuth2 Callback?

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0

I am trying to implement OAuth2 where the Authorization server is [Notion](https://developers.notion.com/reference/create-a-token)

My flow is as follows -

1. [client] User navigates to my website and clicks button to authorize with Notion
2. [Notion Auth server] user gives permission to certain pages within their workspace and notion redirects to my call back
3. [server] I have the the access code and call Notion Auth server to get the token
4. [Notion Auth server] Receives access code and sends back token
5. [server] I have the token and would like to store it in Redis with the user id

I cannot figure out a way to get the user id in my call back to associate it with the token?  Notion doesn't seem to have any [pass through parameters](https://developers.notion.com/docs/authorization#step-4-notion-responds-with-an-access_token-and-additional-information) where I could send the user Id.  I know I must be misunderstanding something, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the Notion API has an endpoint that lets you return information about the owner of an acccess token:

https://developers.notion.com/reference/get-self

Comment: This will return a response that includes the notion "bot user id".  I also get that info when I create the token.  So if I change step 5 ... 
5. [server] Store it in Redis with the bot user id (Ex. "16d84278-ab0e-484c-9bdd-b35da3bd8905")
 ... 
6. [client] makes a call to my server using their user id (Ex. 123) 
 ... 

I still have no way to associate the user with the access token in Redis

Comment: @Ashley that page also says: `The bot will have an owner field with information about the person who authorized the integration`

Comment: correct, but my problem persists.  The callback will receive the access token and info about the person who owns the notion workspace (their notion id, name, avatar, etc), but the call back still has no info on the userId used for my app so I can't figure out how to correlate the data in the callback with my user.

Comment: What is the difference exactly? what do you mean 'my user' in this context?

Comment: The UserId my app has assigned to the user.  The one returned by the Notion API is the id that notion uses internally in their system, so it have no correlation to the one with my app.  I need to be able to correlate the UserId my app has assigned to the user with the access token so on subsequent calls to my app I can retrieve their access token to make calls against Notion.

Comment: I see. usually this is done with a session system. You start the session when the authentication process starts, and when the user gets redirected back to your system you still know for which user you started the authentication process

Comment: "when the user gets redirected back to your system you still know for which user you started the authentication process" - this is the part I'm trying to understand.  The call back from my system comes from Notion's servers so I'm not sure how I would know who the user is?  If the call came from my front end I could include a JWT that has the user id

Comment: No you don't need JWT and they are good to avoid. Basically, if you already have a user system the first time the user auhtenticates with notion, you store the ID you got from notion and associated it to your own user id. It's a bit hard to understand your exact architecture but if you have a correctly functioning session system you should already know what the *local* user id is

Comment: That's the piece I'm trying to figure out - in the call back I have the Notion token/ID, but I don't have the userId my app assigns because the call is coming from Notion not the user.  Do you have any resources I could read to understand it?

Comment: @Ashley no, the redirect back to your application isn't coming from notion. It's your user's browsers doing the request. Notion tells the browser where to go, but the actual thing making the request is a browser that *should* still have an open session.

Comment: Okay maybe that's the part I'm misunderstanding... I will give it a try